# "assert false" passing verification in a simple class

Tags: dafny

This is a minimal dafny program that should fail verification, since it contains an `assert false` statement.  However, it is passing for me using VSCode with the Dafny plugin (version 3.10).
Presumably I've done something wrong somewhere.

```
class MinimalError {
  var a: nat

  constructor()
    ensures a == 0

  ghost predicate valid()
    ensures valid() == (this.a == 0)

  method Blah()
    modifies this
    requires valid()
  {
    this.a := 2;
    assert false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Observation: Adding `reads this` in predicate makes it not verify. It looks like bug try reporting it https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues

Comment: Thanks.  I've just submitted it.   https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/3911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some useful feedback in a bug report that I submitted https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/3911.

This behavior is not a bug, rather the problem is that I have bad postconditions on the `valid` predicate.

Dafny is not responsible for checking that the pre and postconditions are sane.  The simplest solution in the above case would have been for me to add a body to the `valid` predicate.  Although this body isn't required it would have acted as a sanity check on the postconditions and would have caused Dafny to notice that the postcondition needed a `reads this`.

Similarly if the function has bad preconditions then that will get flagged when the function is actually called somewhere.

So the main takeaway is that even though ghost functions don't require a body, it's very useful to write a body as a sanity check.